# data type with two dependent type parameters

Tags: haskell

I have two types

```
data MyType0 a = MyType0 (Set a)        (Set a) [a] a
data MyType1 a = MyType0 (Map a String) (Set a) [a] a
```

This is a contrived example, just to show that these types differ by the first parameter and have a large total number of parameters.

Can I declare a type with two parameters:

```
data MyType a b = MyType b (Set a) [a] a
```

and tell the type checker that I want `b` to be a type parameterized by `a`? That is, I do not want to be able to have a type like `MyType (Set Int) (Set String) [String] String`.

I hope what I am asking makes sense. I am still learning.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I probably will not do it because it would make the code complicated. I just thought about it and realized that I do not know whether this is possible. So I asked...

Comment: I think there are a couple of options `data MyType a b = MyType (b a) (Set a) [a] a` for example but this would require you to do a *type-flip* for your map: `data Flip t a b = Flip (t b a)`: `type MyType1 a = MyType a (Flip Map String)`

Comment: @Carsten thanks. it makes sense. I did not know that I can apply one parameter to another.

Comment: @akonsu **kinds** for the win ;) - there is plenty of other stuff you could use (or so I think): functional-dependencies, type-families, ... but this all require ghc-language-extensions and might be a bit overkill (just as my commented *solution* is ;) )

Comment: Carsten's solution may seem overkill, but modeling a problem accurately like this can have surprising benefits that are worth exploring!